# Cut and paste a range of cells to a select destination

Tags: excel, vba, range, paste, cut

I want to cut and paste a range of cells (ex. A2:D2 to B1:E1) and then repeat this process for 692 rows.

[image]

I have been trying to do this in macros however have been unsuccessful.

```
Sub cut_paste() 
    Dim nr As Integer 
    For nr = 1 To 692 
        Range("A" & nr).Select 
        Selection.Cut 
        Range("B" & nr).Select 
        ActiveSheet.Paste 
        Range("B" & nr).Select 
        Selection.Cut 
        Range("C" & nr).Select 
        ActiveSheet.Paste 
        Range("C" & nr).Select 
        Selection.Cut 
        Range("D" & nr).Select 
        ActiveSheet.Paste 
        Range("D" & nr).Select 
        Selection.Cut 
        Range("E" & nr).Select 
        ActiveSheet.Paste 
    Next nr 
End Sub
```

> ERROR 4001

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: Sub cut_paste()

Dim nr As Integer
For nr = 1 To 692

Range("A" & nr).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B" & nr).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B" & nr).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C" & nr).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C" & nr).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("D" & nr).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D" & nr).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("E" & nr).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next nr

End Sub

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments.  As you can see, it's hard to read/understand. Instead, please add the code to your original post and format with the code tags (`{}`).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 3 To Lastrow Step 2
            .Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Cut .Range("B" & i - 1 & ":E" & i - 1)
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Plus1 for coding standards. Only thing I would point out is that, I think OP want's to start with row 2, so you might want to start your loop from 2

Comment: @JNevill in my opinion if the loop starts from row 2 (ERA Colonial Real Estate) row 2 will paste in row 1 (Filters). That s why i start my code from row 3.

Comment: @error1004 thank you for the assistance. I have one comment with this code block that I forgot to mention. I need to cut and paste every other row. So every odd row needs to be pasted up a row and to the right one column. (example of what I need from the image: A2: ERA Colonial B2: Harker Heights C3: TX D2: 5 E2: 1991)

Comment: To copy paste every other row you must use Step 2 (see code on For i=3...)

Comment: I did use the step two code and still was not getting what I wanted. I apologize for my beginner level knowledge of this program.

Comment: ok. Upload a photo with your data showing column & rows headers and the desirable outcome.

Comment: @Error1004 I have added the pictures to the imgur link in the OP. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for the patience!!

Answer (score 1):

First you create a loop for rows 2 through 692:

```
For i = 2 to 692
    'code to execute in the loop goes here
Next i
```

Then in that loop you do your copy/paste

```
For i = 2 to 692
    Sheet1.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B" & i - 1 & ":E" & i - 1)
Next i
```